# Focus on div appear only on clicking scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, focus, scrollbar

```
    app.directive("keyboardGridAccess", function ($timeout) {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on("keydown", function (event) {
                $timeout(function () {                       
                    if (event.which === 9) {
                        $('.eft-body-col').first().find('span').attr('tabindex', 1).focus();

                    }
                 }, 0);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Focus on class'.left-body-col' shows only when i click on scrollbar. is anything I need do to focus just on clicking tab ?

Comment: `$timeout` is visible, Are you using [tag:anuglarjs]?

Comment: @Satpal Yes i am using angular js, do you think it make any difference ?

Comment: Yes, Its make lot of difference, Can you share the complete code?

Comment: I have shared code angular code

Comment: can u add a working fiddle ?